# css grid layout different number of columns in each row

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid container like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
    <div class="d">D</div>
    <div class="e">E</div>
</div>
```

I am using `grid-template-areas` to position them like this:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        'a b .'
        'c d e';
}

.a {grid-area: 'a';}
.b {grid-area: 'b';}
.c {grid-area: 'c';}
.d {grid-area: 'd';}
.e {grid-area: 'e';}
```

Which looks like this:

```
_____________
| A | B |   |
| C | D | E |
```

However, I would like the number of columns in each row to be independent of the other rows, so I would like something like this:

```
grid-template-areas:
    'a b'
    'c d e';
```

and I would like the following result:

```
_____________
|  A  |  B  |
| C | D | E |
```

The code above does not work. The only solution I came up with was to get the lowest common denominator of the number of columns in each row: 2 x 3 = 6. Then I would repeat each area the number of times necessary:

```
grid-template-areas:
    'a a a b b b'
    'c c d d e e';
```

The problem is that I might have an lcd of two hundred or something, and this would probably be very slow at calculating and rendering.

Is there any way I can achieve this without doing the above? I still need to use one grid layout so that I can completely shift around all the elements when there are different screen sizes, which means I can't just use separate grids for each row.

Comment: Something like this?  https://jsfiddle.net/f1trane3/24/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Am not sure if you can easily do this with grid, but with flexbox it's easy to do and you can always adjust the `order` property to change the layout on small screens.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height:300px;
}
.a,.b {
  flex-basis:calc(100% / 2);
}
.c,.d,.e {
  flex-basis:calc(100% / 3);
}

.container > div {
  border:1px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
  <div class="e">E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks good for the above example, but would this work for example if I wanted it to look the same as `grid-template-areas: 'A B C' 'A D E'`?

Comment: @DavidCallanan i would say yes ;) it need som code adjustement but it can be done with flex ... here is an example : https://jsfiddle.net/gxntjfr0/2/ adjust the screen size to see both layout

Comment: Nice! But is it possible to have a flex-direction of row and column at the same time so that I can do more complex layouts?

Comment: @DavidCallanan within the same container no :) you can have eiher row or column, but if you have nested container you can ... by the way there is a lot of other property that may help to adjust the layout using flexbox ;)